# Does Apple share the appstore user detail with the app in iphone?

Tags: iphone, object, app-store

Does Apple share the user id with the app? If it does, then it might be good to use that id to identify the app user.

Answer (score 1):

No apple does not share any detail about the user how but your app. You may request detail, like enail address from the user but this has to optional and cant be mandatory.